# How to print Sharepoint 2013 Calendars?

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar, printing

Are there any somewhat easy ways to print Sharepoint 2013 calendars in Month or Week views? I'd like to avoid a long custom solution, as this isn't high on our priorities at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a single list/library/calendar AND you are using Outlook, you can import the list/library/calendar into Outlook and print the same format as Outlook calendars:

- Open SharePoint Calendar in Outlook
- Open the calendar that you want to print on the SharePoint website.
- Click "Connect to Outlook" in the "Actions" group on the "Calendar"
  tab.
- Click "Allow" to confirm that you want to allow the SharePoint
  website to open Outlook on your computer. Outlook automatically
  opens.
- Click "Yes" to confirm that you want the SharePoint calendar to
  connect to Outlook. The SharePoint calendar automatically appears in
  Outlook under "Other Calendars."

**Print the SharePoint Calendar**

- Click "Other Calendars" in the navigation pane in the left side of
  the window. Click the SharePoint calendar to open it.
- Click the "File" tab in Microsoft Outlook, then click "Print."
- Select "Calendar Details" style under "Print What" to print the
  complete details of the SharePoint calendar.
- Click "Print Options" to select print options such as the date range
  or printing a specific page. Click "Print" after selecting your
  options to print the SharePoint calendar.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to create another calendar view where you modify the size of the web part to 900 pixels. The calendar grid view now fits on a normal sheet of paper when you check it though the browsers print preview. This is easier for the users to change views and print from the browser instead of going though all the steps to connect to outlook.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a blank calendar in Outlook
- Connect the SharePoint calendar to Outlook
- List item View the linked SharePoint calendar as a list
- Copy the list items to the new, blank Outlook Calendar
- Make sure only the newly filled "blank" Outlook calendar is the only one selected
- Export to CSV file
- Upload the CSV file to a blank Google Calendar Print

Voila!